# TFS2017.2 Build always "cleans" (gets new code) every build - why

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a new TFS build (on premises) that gets all of the code every time it runs. I have Clean set to false both at the Get Sources and the build step. I'm pretty sure that this wasn't happening about a week ago when I first started using TFS2017 Build, but now every build re-gets the code. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the build logs? Does get resource step download all the files in the project or just the dll files? Does this issue occur if you disable all the build tasks in the build definition just keep get source step?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I mapped a Folder and its Subfolder at the same time, but didn't realize that. Removing the Subfolder mapping then resolves the issue.

This is how I found out:

1. Queue new build with variable `system.debug` set to `true`
2. Look at the log while building and spot something like (`** **`) this:

   `**Attempting to find a workspace: 'ws_4_56'**
   Skipping workspace: 'ws_1_56'
   Skipping workspace: 'ws_2_55'
   Skipping workspace: 'ws_3_56'
   Candidate workspace: 'ws_4_56'
   **Expected number of mappings: '57'. Actual: '56'**
   Skipping workspace: 'ws_5_56'
   Skipping workspace: 'ws_6_56'
   **Matching workspace not found.**`
3. If you have an expected mappings number higher than actual, then you have to check which mapping is redundant by comparing the agent output at `<Workspace computer="xxxxx" islocal="true" name="ws_4_56" ...>` with the mappings in the TFS UI.
4. Delete all subfolder mappings that are already included in a folder mapping.

Comment: Thanks Flupp - you're a genius! I've only tested this so far on one build, but it seems to be the case that duplicate trees causes this to happen. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried this on another build where there were no subfolders of mapped folders and it still gets everythying :-(

Answer (score 0):

Suggest your compare the build log for some build runs, check if there are using the same workspace on the build agent.

If there are multiple workspaces, you may using multiple build agents. Cleaning is not relevant if you are getting a new agent every time. You could [specify a vNext build agent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2017/02/08/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server/) in the build definition and then queue multiple times for test.

Also try to explicitly define the `Build.Clean` variable and set its value to below on the **Variables** tab:

- `all` if you want to delete `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`, which is the
  entire working folder that contains the sources folder, binaries
  folder, artifact folder, and so on.
- `source` if you want to delete `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.
- `binary` If you want to delete `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`.

Another way to narrow down the issue is remote to the build agent, check the files under the `C:\TFS2017_agent\_work\3\S\XX` are deleted or not during the build process.

If all above is not working, try to recreate a build definition with same setting which may do the trick.

Comment: Not working. And re-creating the build definition would take (waste) over an hour - it's a pretty big definition. I guess it's not a waste of time if it saves me time doing builds down the road, but it would be really painful. If only there was a way to export/import definitions across projects!! (I've formally suggested that on the MS product forum).

Answer (score 0):

Set Build.RepoClean to false in the Variables section. Seems to do the trick

Comment: Nope - doesn't help. This problem went away for a while but now it's back.

Comment: It must be a combination of Clean flag set to False in the Get Source task (drop-down at the bottom) and Build.RepoClean variable (in the Variables section) set to false. Should work for TFS 2017.2